# How do I use WebAppsOperationsExtensions and IWebAppsOperations in Azure C# SDK

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

This is the method I'm trying to use
WebAppsOperationsExtensions.BackupAsync(IWebAppsOperations, String, String, BackupRequestInner, CancellationToken)

However, I don't know how to get IWebAppsOperations object, as the Microsoft implementation is not public.

Documentation is not helpful:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.appservice.fluent.webappsoperationsextensions.backupasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_AppService_Fluent_WebAppsOperationsExtensions_BackupAsync_Microsoft_Azure_Management_AppService_Fluent_IWebAppsOperations_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Management_AppService_Fluent_Models_BackupRequestInner_System_Threading_CancellationToken_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congratulations on your fist post!

I have worked with Azure for years but have not done much work with Azure SDK .NET. So I was happy to dig deeper into your problem and experience the challenge.

I followed these steps to provide you with an answer:

**Step 1** - Explore documentation in detail

Opened your link. First thing I observed was that **WebAppsOperationsExtensions.BackupAsync** is an extension method. The MSDN title presents it as **WebAppsOperationsExtensions.BackupAsync(IWebAppsOperations, String, String, BackupRequestInner, CancellationToken) Method** but pay close attention to "this" in definition of the first parameter code example in the article:

> public static
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent.Models.BackupItemInner>
> BackupAsync (this
> Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent.IWebAppsOperations
> operations, string resourceGroupName, string name,
> Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent.Models.BackupRequestInner
> request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken =
> default);

So this method is an extension method.

**Step 2** - Explore code samples

Scroll the navigation tree menu to find the top most article in the branch: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/appservice?view=azure-dotnet

Found the following code example on usage:

```
/* Include these "using" directives...
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent;
*/

IWebApp app1 = azure.WebApps
    .Define("MyUniqueWebAddress")
    .WithRegion(Region.USWest)
    .WithNewResourceGroup("MyResourceGroup")
    .WithNewWindowsPlan(PricingTier.StandardS1)
    .Create();
```

**Step 3** - Prototype

Open Visual Studio 2019 and attempt to find your answer by reading helpful article: https://dotnetdevlife.wordpress.com/2020/01/16/quickstart-azure-management-libraries-for-net/comment-page-1/

[image]

To summarize, I was able to pass IWebAppsOperations into WebAppsOperationsExtensions.BackupAsync by invoking BackupAsync as an extension method of azure.WebApps.Inner. For that to work I needed to add extra nuget packages (see using statements in the screenshot for the list).

Note: I have not provided you with full implementation of BackupAsync as it was not your question.

Best regards!

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  This was exactly what I was looking for.